# Python Turtle setworldcoordinates Negative Values

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

EDIT: I've add the code from the turtle module at the end of this question. I can't see why there is `self.screensize(wx-20, wy-20)`, but I expect that is the source of the issue.

I'm confused by `setworldcoordinates()` from the Python `turtle` module. I can't see why my code displays negative x-ccordinates when I click near the left-hand edge of the turtle window, as in the image below.

My code is below. Could someone please explain how to modify it to have the left-hand edge of the window be at exactly `x=0`?

```
import turtle

BLOCK_SIZE = 40
BORDER = 5
STAMP_SIZE = 20
ROWS = 10
COLUMNS = 12

def click_handler(x, y):
    print(x, y)


screen = turtle.Screen()
screen.setup(COLUMNS * (BLOCK_SIZE + BORDER), ROWS * (BLOCK_SIZE + BORDER))
screen.setworldcoordinates(0, 0, screen.window_width(), screen.window_height())
screen.onclick(click_handler)
```

[image]

`setworldcoordinates` definition from `turtle` module:

```py
    def setworldcoordinates(self, llx, lly, urx, ury):
        """Set up a user defined coordinate-system.

        Arguments:
        llx -- a number, x-coordinate of lower left corner of canvas
        lly -- a number, y-coordinate of lower left corner of canvas
        urx -- a number, x-coordinate of upper right corner of canvas
        ury -- a number, y-coordinate of upper right corner of canvas

        Set up user coodinat-system and switch to mode 'world' if necessary.
        This performs a screen.reset. If mode 'world' is already active,
        all drawings are redrawn according to the new coordinates.

        But ATTENTION: in user-defined coordinatesystems angles may appear
        distorted. (see Screen.mode())

        Example (for a TurtleScreen instance named screen):
        >>> screen.setworldcoordinates(-10,-0.5,50,1.5)
        >>> for _ in range(36):
        ...     left(10)
        ...     forward(0.5)
        """
        if self.mode() != "world":
            self.mode("world")
        xspan = float(urx - llx)
        yspan = float(ury - lly)
        wx, wy = self._window_size()
        self.screensize(wx-20, wy-20)
        oldxscale, oldyscale = self.xscale, self.yscale
        self.xscale = self.canvwidth / xspan
        self.yscale = self.canvheight / yspan
        srx1 = llx * self.xscale
        sry1 = -ury * self.yscale
        srx2 = self.canvwidth + srx1
        sry2 = self.canvheight + sry1
        self._setscrollregion(srx1, sry1, srx2, sry2)
        self._rescale(self.xscale/oldxscale, self.yscale/oldyscale)
        self.update()
```

Answer (score 1):

There are three sizes to consider: size of the window on the screen; size of the visible area of the window we can draw on; size of the window's canvas backing store that we can scroll.  I believe you can adjust the third using turtle's `screensize()` method.

Between the size of the window on the screen and the the size of the visible drawing area sits the *chrome*, the window's overhead of borders and border shadows, etc.  It seems like turtle is simply estimating these instead of calculating them based on window system characteristics:

```
self.screensize(wx-20, wy-20)
```

This uncommented magic `-20` appears nowhere else in the turtle code.  I'd guess the tkinter underpinnings could provide an exact value.

The two problems I see are that turtle's estimate can be off *and* `onclick()` is registering clicks on a portion of the chrome (on my system), which doesn't make sense.  The best I could come up with is compounding it with an estimated correction:

```
from turtle import Screen

BLOCK_SIZE = 40
BORDER = 5

ROWS = 10
COLUMNS = 12

WIDTH = COLUMNS * (BLOCK_SIZE + BORDER)
HEIGHT = ROWS * (BLOCK_SIZE + BORDER)

CHROME = 7  # correction guesstimate for OS X

def click_handler(x, y):
    print(x, y)

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.setworldcoordinates(CHROME, CHROME, WIDTH, HEIGHT)
screen.onclick(click_handler)
screen.mainloop()
```

If you click on the left or bottom chrome, you should get values < zero (I won't say *negative* as -0.0 turns up here) until you click on the drawable part of the window.  The right and top will produce values greater than the calculated width and height if you click on the chrome, but within them otherwise.

Again, I believe the real solution lies in turtle's tkinter underpinnings.